# Dynamic coordinate randomizer with constraints

Tags: geometry

I have a domain described by $[x_\min , y_\min]$ and $[x_\max , y_\max] $as shown in the following picture
[image]
I want to find random coordinates $[(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),\ldots, (x_n,y_n)]$ of circles with a certain radius and separated by a certain distance delta to be fit inside the domain. I have an upper limit ($n$) to the number of circles that can be fit inside the domain. I want to use python to code this randomizer hence the number of circles needs to vary according to the radius and value delta. How could this problem be solved?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How is this relevant I have absolutely no equations in the question